# ExtJS 4 grid update the grid after adding a new record

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, grid

I am working on Ext Grid. and I use proxy to do CRUD operations. But my problem is that, once I add the new row in grid, I am not able to update the grid with new record. Could anyone help me out in this or give me hint ? I am using Spring MVC, Mybatis.

Thanks.
J.M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using editor grid? or Gridpanel?

If you are using GridPanel try with

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('yourgridID');
grid.getStore().reload(params);
```